# Use of := and = in ggvis property assignments

Tags: r, operators, ggvis

The primer page for ggvis interactivity

http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html#property-mappings

provides the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_smooths(span = input_slider(0.5, 1, value = 1)) %>%
  layer_points(size := input_slider(100, 1000, value = 100))
```

The code functions correctly in rstudio/knitr/shiny environment.

My question concerns the use of the = assignment operator in the layer_smooths() function, but the use of := operator in the layer_points() function.  In both functions, a property (span or size is being defined, and the same shiny function (input_slider) is being called to assign that property.

Why are there two distinct assignment operators = and := ? and what distinguishes them from each other?

Comment: No idea, but this post on Google groups by Hadley Wickham mentions it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/pKlvZFkxzZM

Comment: Well done thelatemail ! I did not find this reference.  However, the meaning (despite Hadley's usual eloquence) remains a bit opaque to me... how is size unscaled but span is scaled... ?

Comment: The meaning is pretty opaque to me too. @hadley does float around these parts from time-to-time, so maybe he might enlighten us further.

Comment: This has the potential to trip up many an experienced and amateur user. What exactly is a "raw,  unscaled value"  and how is it different from other values which are neither raw nor unscaled.

Answer (score 3):

I found this in ggvis documentation
"If you want to make the points a fixed colour or size, you need to use := instead of =. The := operator means to use a raw, unscaled value." for details see
http://ggvis.rstudio.com/properties-scales.html